# When using media queries to optimise for iOS, website header is pushed to one side

Tags: css, ios, media-queries

My website (http://amosjackson.com) uses css media queries to resize the website so that it fits an iPhone screen. When I view the site (on an iPhone 4), a block of background shows through to the right of the header. The header is width:100% and so should be from edge to edge. I haven't properly coded the css for non-retina iOS (it looks worse on older iDevices) so please don't comment on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is the `padding: 10px;` in combination with `width: 100%;` in the `#nav` element. Drop the padding an it should work.